# How to set Basic Constraints to End Entity using pwoershell new-SelfsignedCertificate?

Tags: powershell, certificate

Is there a way to set the Basic Constraintextension to Subject Type=End Entity using command like

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -Type Custom -Subject "E=patti.fuller@contoso.com,CN=Patti Fuller" -TextExtension @("2.5.29.37={text}1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.4")
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the article [Using the Basic Constraints extension in X.509 v3 certificates for intermediate CAs](http://unitstep.net/blog/2009/03/16/using-the-basic-constraints-extension-in-x509-v3-certificates-for-intermediate-cas/). There is also a good [post](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/31891dc9-cd6b-4209-b463-00859cdd5081/newselfsignedcertificate-set-basic-constraint-subject-is-end-entity?forum=winserverpowershell) on msdn.com.